# asp.net button causing two post asynchronous post backs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

this button is causing two post backs .

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="asdd" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnNew" class="imgbtnNew" runat="server" CausesValidation="false"
                                            ImageUrl="~/Administrative/images/fullpage.gif" OnClick="imgbtnNew_Click" />
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

this code shows how i checked this behaviour

```
function pageLoad()
    {
    alert("Page load");      
       var manager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();      
       manager.add_beginRequest(OnBeginRequest);
       manager.add_endRequest(OnEndRequest);
    }
    function OnBeginRequest(sender, args)
    {

      var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
      alert("Begin" + postBackElement.id);          
   }
   function OnEndRequest(sender, args)
    {
    alert("end req caled!");
      var postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();
      if (postBackElement.className == 'imgbtnNew')  
      { 
     $get('upc1').style.display = "block"; 
      }
   }
```

Another problem is that this behavior is occurring only when the button is clicked second time the page was loaded. it shows single alert for both begin and end request but the second time the button is clicked it shows two alerts for begin request and no alert is shown for end request and the click event handler is executed once per click as it should . So the button behaves properly for the first time it is clicked but not after that .

Comment: on the second time you have some error get it from the first time. Open your javascript console to see what its says. You may have some viewstate corruption because you do not have "setup" correct the content of the updatepanel.

Comment: @Ivan - function pageLoad() is called every time the page is loaded.

Comment: my mistake .......  args.get_postBackElement() is not a method in args of endrequest  . get_postBackElement can be used only in OnBeginRequest handler ..   thanks @Aristos for your suggestion

Comment: if you find your error, make it an answer - you may help others in the future

Comment: @Aristos -I thought the only problem was that i was using args.get_postBackElement() method in OnEndRequest . But after removing args.get_postBackElement() from OnEndRequest still OnEndRequest is not getting called for the second click of the button . So the problem is still the same . Button click is behaving differently for second click . Please help

Answer (score 0):

finally i got it. endRequest and beginRequest handlers were added but not removed from the PageRequestManager instance that's why begin request was getting called again and again. EndRequest handler was not executed because i was using get_postBackElement() in OnEndRequest  method that raised an error , as a result the request was not ending and update progress control was showing continuously .